# Zend: Adding a Newline after Radio Button

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, radio-button

I have a form in that has a question with two radio buttons.  However, they are showing up one immediately after the other.  I would like to add a separator between them, but am having issues.  I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work.

This is what I have in my .phtml:

```
<h3>Options</h3>
<section>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_REVIEW_PROJECT); ?>
</section>
```

This successfully displays the radio buttons.

Now for my `Form.php`:

Attempt 1:

```
$review = new Radio(self::KEY_REVIEW_PROJECT); 
$review->setValueOptions(array(
    'Yes' => 'Yes, this is a review project', 
    'No' => 'No, not a review project'   
)); 
$review->setLabel("Review Project");
$review->setOptions(array('separator' => "\n"));
```

Nothing changed.

Attempt 2:

```
$review = new Radio(self::KEY_REVIEW_PROJECT); 
$review->setValueOptions(array(
    'Yes' => 'Yes, this is a review project', 
    'No' => 'No, not a review project'   
)); 
$review->setLabel("Review Project");
$review->setLabelAttributes(array('separator' => "\n"));
```

Still no luck.  Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I would add a class to the radio buttons and then add a style for them, something like .radio-button{display:block;}

Comment: @jpganz18 Well I'd really like to do it using Zend

Comment: Not 100% sure on this and unable to test but shouldn't the `\n` be `<br />`? Unless the Zend_Form viewScript does some automagic behind the scenes, the browser wont render a newline unless a `<br />` tag is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to be on separate lines by just commenting your last line of code.

```
$review = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('test');
$review->setMultiOptions(array(
    'Yes' => ' Yes, this is a review project',
    'No' => ' No, not a review project'
));
$review->setLabel("Review Project");
//$review->setOptions(array('separator' => "\n"));

echo $review;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a difference between `setMultiOptions` and `setValueOptions`?

Comment: when I used `setValueOptions` Zend gave me an error and the correct way i got mine working was by using `setMultiOptions` .  I am using Zend 1.12.   Did you come right ?